# Partition mysql table based on months

Tags: mysql

I'm newbie in MySql. Supposed I have a table like this:

```
**Month table**
-----------------
id  month data
1    1    0.5
2    1    0.8
3    2    0.12
4    2    0.212
5    2    1.4
6    3    5.7
7    4    6.8
```

How can I split it into different tables based on month and have those tables available in disk. If that's possible, how can I later refer to these tables later. For example:

```
**January table**
-----------------
id   month data
1     1     0.5
2     1     0.8

**February table**
-----------------
id   month  data
1     2     0.12
2     2     0.212
3     2     1.4

**March table**
-----------------
id   month  data
1     3     5.7

**April table**
-----------------
id   month  data
1     4     6.8
```

etc.

Thank you for your help.

I looked into partition by range but I don't think it serves my purpose because it is not creating smaller tables. I was thinking of writing a procedure but don't know where to start.

Comment: Strictly in described form - noway. `Month` column must present in each partition.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the description

Comment: Please decide what do you need really. #1 - partitioning (one table which consists from 12 partitions); #2 - 12 separate independent tables. PS. Creating separate tables is wrong idea. If you need in this then create 12 views based on one table.

Comment: What is the purpose of the partitioning?

Comment: @Akina I see, I'll probably need to avoid it, but for now I'll look into views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to simply speed up queries by month, just add an index to your month or timestamp column. Partitions speed things up, but they can also slow things down.

> *I looked into partition by range but I don't think it serves my purpose because it is not creating smaller tables.*

[This is incorrect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-overview.html).

> Partitioning takes this notion a step further, by enabling you to distribute portions of individual tables across a file system according to rules which you can set largely as needed. In effect, different portions of a table are stored as separate tables in different locations.

You can [alter your existing table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) into 12 partitions by month. If you already have a month column...

```
alter table month_table
partition by list(month) (
  partition January values in (1),
  partition February values in (1),
  -- etc ---
);
```

And if you have a date or timestamp column, turn it into a month.

```
alter table month_table
partition by list(month(created_at)) (
  partition January values in (1),
  partition February values in (1),
  -- etc ---
);
```

> *...how can I later refer to these tables later*

Generally, you don't refer to the individual partitions. You insert and query the main table. The point of partitioning is to be transparent. If there is an applicable `where` clause that will read from the related partition.

```
-- This will read from the February partition.
select * from month_table where "month" = 2;

-- This will read from both the February and March partitions.
select * from month_table where "month" in (2,3);
```

But you can query the individual partitions with a partition clause using the name of the partition.

```
SELECT * FROM month_table PARTITION (January);
```

You generally do not need to do this except to debug what is in each partition.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So basically partition will help speed up select query on table with a lot of rows - instead of full table look up it will look in the partition? Also, in the example we know the number of partitions is 12, but what if we don't know how many partitions we need?

Comment: @Tony 1) Partitions *can* help with performance, but they can also hurt it. Your primary performance tools should be good schemas and indexes. An index on the `month` column should solve a performance problem better than partitioning. 2) With a hash partition, the hashed values will be distributed across how ever many partitions you make. With a list or range partition, you already know how many partitions you need.

Comment: I doubt  that partitioning by hash is correct. You'd test, it is possible that two months should be placed into the same partition whereas some partition will be empty. And you'd take into account if a column is nullable. I think that range partitioning is more correct.

Comment: @Akina I thought it was kinda odd, but it's an example they use in the docs. :shrug: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-overview.html I don't think partitioning is the correct solution here, sounds like all that's needed is an index.